# Listview control in VB6

Tags: listview, vb6

I need to invisible the listview control when click a item in listview. I wrote a example. But it is not working.I added Column headers and few items.
I used 'windows common control 6.0(sp6)'

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemClick(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
  ListView1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

please help me.

Comment: So what does happen?

Comment: Mr. Alex,
Does not invisible the ListView . It is working for click,DblClick etc. except Itemclick event .
please help

Comment: Very strange. I tried your code sample and the ListView just remains visible. I can't think of a reason to do something like this, but you can fake it by moving it off the screen with something like `ListView1.Left = -ListView1.Width`.

Comment: thanks. yes, that is a alternative method. But it is difficult method for my need.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the ListView restores its own visibility when `ItemClick` returns control to it, the same appears to be true for `MouseDown`.

This works:

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
    Dim clickedItem As MSComctlLib.ListItem
    Set clickedItem = ListView1.HitTest(x, y)
    If Not clickedItem Is Nothing Then ListView1.Visible = False
End Sub
```